# mysql connector call by column name instead of index

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

In order to fetch a `SELECT` statement, that's what I usually do:

```
stmt_select = "SELECT * FROM {0} ORDER BY id".format(tbl)
cursor.execute(stmt_select)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    output.append("%3s | %10s | %19s | %8s |" % (
        row[0],
        row[1],
        row[2],
        row[3],
    ))
```

The problem of this method is that I need to specify index column instead of the column name. How can I access specifying column name instead of specifying always the index? Preferibly without specify the column names that I want to fetch in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common use of [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), you can create a namedtuple - and it allows property access.

Example that correlates the the code from the question:

```
from collections import namedtuple
DBEntity = namedtuple("DBEntity", ("first_cell","second_cell","third_cell", "fourth_cell"))
stmt_select = "SELECT * FROM {0} ORDER BY id".format(tbl)
cursor.execute(stmt_select)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    t_row = DBEntity(*row)
    output.append("%3s | %10s | %19s | %8s |" % (
        t_row.first_cell,
        t_row.seconnd_cell,
        t_row.third_cell,
        t_row.fourth_cell,
    ))
```

Additionally(though might be a bit of an overkill depending on your program's purpose) - You can also use [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/) for ORM

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think that will work but as you say I saw this module a bit without functions. I opted for pymysql that seems more easy.